# Obtener top 50 por categoría MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

cree el siguiente script que me devuelve el top50 por sucursal:

```
    select  
    S.SUC AS 'Sucursal',
    S.ART AS 'Cod. Articulo',
    ART.B1 AS 'Marca Propia',
    ART.A2 AS 'Rubro',
    sum(if(TIPSTO = 'F', EXI, IF(TIPSTO = 'C', EXI *-1,0))) AS 'STOCK'
    FROM ST_STOCK S
    INNER JOIN ST_ARTICULO ART ON ART.ID = S.ART
    INNER JOIN ST_ATR_A2 A2 ON A2.ID = ART.A2
    WHERE S.DEP = 1 AND S.SUC = 2 AND ART.DISCONTINUO = 'N' AND ART.ACTIVO = 'S' 
    GROUP by SUC, ART
    ORDER BY EXI DESC
    LIMIT 50
```

;`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que estoy teniendo es que tengo 10 sucursales, por lo que tengo que ejecutar esa consulta 10 veces modificando en el where s.suc = xxx.

Como podría en el mismo script realizar el top50 de artículos con mayor stock separados por sucursal? Es decir, la consulta debería devolverme 500 líneas (50 por sucursal).

Gracias de antemano, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so].  Por favor consulta [ask] y luego publica el código de la consulta, si no muestras lo que has intentado no podrán ayudarte.

Comment: Publiqué el código, y hasta una imagen. No entiendo a que te referís.